# Understanding why this query is slow

Tags: mysql

The below query is very slow (takes around 1 second), but is only searching approx 2500 records (+ inner joined tables).
if i remove the ORDER BY, the query runs in much less time (0.05 or less)
OR if i remove the part nested select below "# used to select where no ProfilePhoto specified" it also runs fast, but i need both of these included.

I have indexes (or primary key) on :tPhoto_PhotoID, PhotoID, p.Enabled, CustomerID, tCustomer_CustomerID, ProfilePhoto (bool), u.UserName, e.PrivateEmail, m.tUser_UserID, Enabled, Active, m.tMemberStatuses_MemberStatusID, e.tCustomerMembership_MembershipID, e.DateCreated
(do i have too many indexes? my understanding is add them anywhere i use WHERE or ON)

The Query :

```
SELECT e.CustomerID,
e.CustomerName,
e.Location,                    
SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.CustomerProfile,' ', 25) AS Description,
IFNULL(p.PhotoURL, PhotoTable.PhotoURL) AS PhotoURL
FROM tCustomer e                  
LEFT JOIN (tCustomerPhoto ep INNER JOIN tPhoto p ON (ep.tPhoto_PhotoID = p.PhotoID AND p.Enabled=1)) 
ON e.CustomerID = ep.tCustomer_CustomerID AND ep.ProfilePhoto = 1
# used to select where no ProfilePhoto specified
LEFT JOIN ((SELECT pp.PhotoURL, epp.tCustomer_CustomerID
FROM tPhoto pp
LEFT JOIN tCustomerPhoto epp ON epp.tPhoto_PhotoID = pp.PhotoID
GROUP BY epp.tCustomer_CustomerID) AS PhotoTable) ON e.CustomerID = PhotoTable.tCustomer_CustomerID
INNER JOIN tUser u ON u.UserName = e.PrivateEmail
INNER JOIN tmembers m ON m.tUser_UserID = u.UserID
WHERE e.Enabled=1
AND e.Active=1
AND m.tMemberStatuses_MemberStatusID = 2
AND e.tCustomerMembership_MembershipID != 6
ORDER BY e.DateCreated DESC
LIMIT 12
```

i have similar queries that but they run much faster.

any opinions would be grateful:

Comment: If you remove the "ORDER BY", the server only needs to return the first 12 rows it finds matching the criteria.  I you include the "ORDER BY", the server needs to find all rows matching the criteria, sort them, and then return the first 12 rows of the sorted set.

Comment: look for the execution plan

Comment: @ronin ok, great, i understand. do you think it would be possible to speed up the nested select, as this is also slowing things down too

Comment: We would need to see your schema and indexes and [EXPLAIN](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Analyzing-Queries-for-Speed-with-EXPLAIN/) result to formulate an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until we get more clarity on your question between working in other query etc..Try `EXPLAIN {YourSelectQuery}` in MySQL client and see the suggestions to improve the performance.

Comment: i wish i knew enough to offer more clarity, i will read up on EXPLAIN, as this is something i have yet to learn. Thanks. For now i have redone the query to remove the nested select and IFNULL statement (and done this in PHP instead) which is much faster now (i just liked the neatness of doing it all in the SQL, but now i see why it is a bad idea....). Thanks...